# How to ignore empty selections in XMLStarlet?

Tags: suppress-warnings, xmlstarlet

I have a script that performs many XML edit operations with [XMLStarlet](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/).
For instance, it removes all `foo` nodes if any are present:

```
xmlstarlet ed -d '//foo'
```

(except that in my script, the name of the element is not `foo`).

When no `foo` node is present, the following message is printed:

```
None of the XPaths matched; to match a node in the default namespace
use '_' as the prefix (see section 5.1 in the manual).
For instance, use /_:node instead of /node
```

But there is nothing wrong if no `foo` nodes are present in the input document.
So for this particular operation, I do want to avoid this particular warning,
while I do not want to disable such warnings in general.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

At the moment, deleting a node that does not exist is categorized by xmlstarlet as an error.  The return code will be `1` which you will have to understand as "no nodes were removed".

The error message appears if you happen to use a document which has a default namespace:

No namespace:

```
echo '<foo />' | xmlstarlet sel -t -m foo -v joe
```

With a default namespace xmlstarlet prints the error message

```
echo '<foo xmlns="urn:foo" />' | xmlstarlet sel -t -m foo -v joe
None of the XPaths matched; to match a node in the default namespace
use '_' as the prefix (see section 5.1 in the manual).
For instance, use /_:node instead of /node
```

No default namespace:

```
echo '<ns:foo xmlns:ns="urn:foo" />' | xmlstarlet sel -t -m foo -v joe
```

In all of these cases, no nodes are found, and xmlstarlet thus exit with return code `1` (i.e. an error).  The error message was to explain the error in the case where the user forgot that the document had a default namespace.  I have discussed this with the author and more recently changes have been introduced to reduce the chances of these messages, and a way to inhibit them.

xmlstarlet has (yet undocumented) support for using the document's namespaces, without needing to declare them up-front:

Compare:

```
echo '<ns:foo xmlns:ns="urn:foo" />' | xmlstarlet sel -t -m ns:foo -v 'count(.)'
echo '<ns:foo xmlns:ns="urn:foo" />' | xmlstarlet sel -N xx=urn:foo -t -m xx:foo -v 'count(.)'
```

Technically, the commands are identical, except the first one depends on the document binding to the 'ns' prefix, while the second does not.

To inhibit the message, you have to redirecting stderr to null:

```
echo '<foo xmlns="urn:xxx"/>' |
xmlstarlet sel -t -m foo -v joe 2> /dev/null
```

The downside of this is that it suppresses legitimate error messages, not just this bogus one which is caused by the fact that the source document uses namespaces.

In recent builds `--no-doc-namespace` has been added to inhibit this behaviour

The change was introduced in [this changeset](https://github.com/mirror/xmlstar/commit/5cb1977bb3127443415a9952b0afad5be9fb54b7) and the changeset contains a long exchange regarding this error message, all caused by this StackOverflow question!

Comment: Yes, that's what I do, too - and I suppose I could filter out just this particular warning with `grep` or some such, but I want to do it from within XMLStarlet.

Comment: The linked changeset now contains some discussion with regards to the problem, so this might fix itself in some future version of xmlstarlet.

Comment: I've just tried the present codebase - the new `--no-doc-namespace` causes the warning to be omitted, which is an improvement, but it doesn't really provide an answer to my question.

Comment: @reinierpost: how is `--no-doc-namespace` not an answer? It suppresses this message and no others.

Comment: It suppresses it when I haven't bothered to specify the right namespaces, which is nice, but not what I'm asking for. What I want is for it to be suppressed in cases when 0 matches do not indicate that there is anything wrong with the input - which is not something XMLStarlet can decide for me.

Comment: I feel the question _has_ been answered, with a "NO" you cannot do this.  I understand of course that it is not the answer you want, but it is an answer nonetheless.  What you _want_ is to be able to get a 0 return code when there are no matches, right?  So would I.  I suggest you make your request noted as an issue on this github project: https://github.com/mirror/xmlstar

Comment: If you change your answer to actually say this, I will accept it. At present it doesn't tell me anything I hadn't figured our before asking the question - except the info about the new option of course.

Comment: I hope you understand that the question "how can I cause this not to be flagged as an error" is not actuially answered by the answer "it is flagged as an error", no matter how helpful the additional detail is.

Comment: @reinierpost: the message was intended only for cases where the user didn't notice the default namespace. In addition to `--no-doc-namespace` I also added some heuristics to suppress more false positives, but I'm still considering whether to remove it completely.

Comment: @mogsie: The official project page is http://sourceforge.net/projects/xmlstar/, the github project is just a mirror.

Comment: @npostavs: I would prefer if it was optional per operation. I have a whole series of XML rewriting operations; in some I just want to rewrite some things in case they are present, in other cases I do expect to have matches.